# Calculating sum of a column based on other columns of a dataframe?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science, data-analysis

I am looking to tweak the code below:

```
df.loc[df['Range'] == '6-10','Actual'].sum()
```

If I want to add another column called city, to this where would I alter this?

For example if Range column value is ***'6-10'*** then I want sum of ***Actual*** column as above in code, but I want to tweak that code so I can also filter of the ***City*** column value is 'NY' for example.

Thanks!

Comment: Combine the two flags with & maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
df.loc[df['Range'].eq('6-10')&df['City'].eq('NY'),'Actual'].sum()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do it two ways:

```
df.loc[(df['Range'] == '6-10') & (df['City'] == 'NY'),'Actual'].sum()
```

Or another which might be more extensible

```
query_str = "(Range == '6-10') and (City == 'NY')"
df.query(query_str)['Actual'].sum()
```

Comment: Thanks for showing how to use `query()`. I think it's much easier to understand!